# How to replace missing values with mean of one of the category of that column in R?

Tags: r, statistics

```
Cars       MPG
Ford        12
Toyota      20
Honda       18
Ford        15
Ford        17
Toyota      24
Ford         NA
Ford         NA
```

so i want to replace the missing values with mean of the Ford's MPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you could use `ave` to do the group level operation as follows.

An inner function with two lines:

```
ave(DF$MPG, DF$Cars, FUN=function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE); x})
[1] 12.00000 20.00000 18.00000 15.00000 17.00000 24.00000 14.66667 14.66667
```

Here, `x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)` replaces missing values with the mean of the non-missing values then the next line returns the full group vector.

in one line with `replace`

```
ave(DF$MPG, DF$Cars, FUN=function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
[1] 12.00000 20.00000 18.00000 15.00000 17.00000 24.00000 14.66667 14.66667
```

Of course, add to assign back to the data.frame,

```
DF$MPG <- ave(DF$MPG, DF$Cars, FUN=function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(Cars)%>%mutate(MPG=ifelse(is.na(MPG),mean(MPG,na.rm=T),MPG))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   Cars [3]
    Cars      MPG
   <chr>    <dbl>
1   Ford 12.00000
2 Toyota 20.00000
3  Honda 18.00000
4   Ford 15.00000
5   Ford 17.00000
6 Toyota 24.00000
7   Ford 14.66667
8   Ford 14.66667
```

Answer (score 0):

`na.aggregate` will replace NAs with the average of the non-NAs and `ave` can be used to apply this by `Cars`:

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, MPG = ave(MPG, Cars, FUN = na.aggregate))
```

giving:

```
    Cars      MPG
1   Ford 12.00000
2 Toyota 20.00000
3  Honda 18.00000
4   Ford 15.00000
5   Ford 17.00000
6 Toyota 24.00000
7   Ford 14.66667
8   Ford 14.66667
```

**Note:**  The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
Cars       MPG
Ford        12
Toyota      20
Honda       18
Ford        15
Ford        17
Toyota      24
Ford         NA
Ford         NA"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions that manage to use `replace_na` but lose the row order:

```
df %>% split(.$Cars) %>% map_df(~replace_na(.x,list(MPG=mean(.x$MPG,na.rm=T))))
df %>% by(.$Cars,function(x) replace_na(x,list(MPG=mean(x$MPG,na.rm=T)))) %>% unclass %>% bind_rows

#     Cars      MPG
# 1   Ford 12.00000
# 2   Ford 15.00000
# 3   Ford 17.00000
# 4   Ford 14.66667
# 5   Ford 14.66667
# 6  Honda 18.00000
# 7 Toyota 20.00000
# 8 Toyota 24.00000
```